# Is there an optimal value for ALPHA in Lasso CV or ridge CV which we can put up most of the times?

Tags: model

I have like 10 datasets and I want to know if I can have an optimal alpha value for Lasso or Ridge... Will it create problems like under fitting or over fitting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Alpha Selection Visualizer demonstrates how different values of alpha influence model selection during the regularization of linear models. Generally speaking, alpha increases the affect of regularization, e.g. if alpha is zero there is no regularization and the higher the alpha, the more the regularization parameter influences the final model.
'
Alphas that are too high on the other hand increase the error due to bias (underfit). It is important, therefore to choose an optimal Alpha such that the error is minimized in both directions.

First: trying to set alpha to find a pre-specified number of important features isn't a good idea.

When I was a beginner at ML, I remember doing that for some 20 datasets where I had 100 as the alpha value in LASSO and it worked amazing. (improved) But then the 21st dataset was underfitting. So, without cross validation and hyper tuning of other parameters, I won't recommend this. Also what is the need of specifying a pre-defined optimal value when you can compute them?